# Round a float number in c#

Tags: c#, math

i get 4 byte data in network as float point number and when i convert it to a float number, result is like this: "7.346952E-40", but i want to show this number to user. when i round this number with Math.Round() function, result is "0.000". how can i round this float number to a simple float number like this: 123.456?

Comment: well because math.round will round to nearest whole number. Are you kidding? What else would you want to show? Do you know what 7.346952E-40 equals?Incredibly small number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number 7.346952E-40 is actually 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000007346952, so when you round it to 4 decimal places you get 0.0000.

Answer (score 0):

7.346952E-40 (7.346952 x 10^-40) is actually really close of 0, your rounding function is correct.

You can also use number.ToString("0.000") or number.ToString("#.###") to display your number depending of if you want only significant digits or a constant length number, like for currencies.

Answer (score -1):

Just Console.writeline(xxx.ToString("0.000"))